# Multiply an object based on its quantity attribute

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm a newbie, struggling in this new world.

I have this array of objects:

```
[
  {
    "orderid": "12696",
    "id": 5180,
    "name": "Crema Chantilly 250 Ml",
    "price": 377.2,
    **"quantity": 1,**
    "order": 0,
    "category": 167
  },
  {
    "orderid": "12696",
    "id": 3929,
    "name": "Close Up",
    "price": 111.15,
    **"quantity": 2,**
    "order": 1,
    "category": 156
  },
  {
    "orderid": "12696",
    "id": 2739,
    "name": "Hellmanns 232 Ml",
    "price": 92.68,
    **"quantity": 2,**
    "order": 31,
    "category": 131
  }
]
```

These are product cards which will get scanned by a barcode scanner, for a warehouse picking app. I'm doing it as a sort of multi-step form for this. I need the objects to be multiplied by its quantity so, I can get to pick each item.
I'm using sequelize to get everything from the database, and then a .map() to make a new array of objects of what i need from the product card.

This is an example of what i'm seeking:

```
[
  {
    "orderid": "12696",
    "id": 5180,
    "name": "Crema Chantilly 250 Ml",
    "price": 377.2,
    **"quantity": 1,**
    "order": 0,
    "category": 167
  },
  {
    "orderid": "12696",
    "id": 3929,
    "name": "Close Up",
    "price": 111.15,
    **"quantity": 2,**
    "order": 1,
    "category": 156
  },
  {
    "orderid": "12696",
    "id": 3929,
    "name": "Close Up",
    "price": 111.15,
    **"quantity": 2,**
    "order": 1,
    "category": 156
  },
  {
    "orderid": "12696",
    "id": 2739,
    "name": "Hellmanns 232 Ml",
    "price": 92.68,
    **"quantity": 2,**
    "order": 31,
    "category": 131
  },
  {
    "orderid": "12696",
    "id": 2739,
    "name": "Hellmanns 232 Ml",
    "price": 92.68,
    **"quantity": 2,**
    "order": 31,
    "category": 131
  }
]
```

I also thought of doing it all on the DOM, using a number input which will decrement as i scan the bar-code of the product, but I can't figure it out how to do it.

Thanks in advance, i would really appreciate your help !

Comment: @JaromandaX Someone ordered 12 items of a product, but, i wasnt going to copy and paste 12 times, i was trying to simulate that. The id is a fake barcode that i added to simulate a product code, which serve me as a validator to compare it to the code that the user inputs.

Comment: Seems like all you really need is another property for `orderQty`. Repeating items in an array is an unusual approach for something like this IMO. Then to fill that item in the order you have everything in one object

Comment: @FluffyKitten oh sorry about that! I'll do that, thanks for the tip, i'm new here!

Comment: No problem. It is entirely up to you whether to upvote or accept any answers you get, but it's always nice to show appreciation for good answers that are helpful :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean by "multiply an object by its quantity"? You want the object to appear that many times in the array? If so, you can use reduce:

```js
const items = [
  {
    "orderid": "12696",
    "id": 5180,
    "name": "Crema Chantilly 250 Ml",
    "price": 377.2,
    "quantity": 1,
    "order": 0,
    "category": 167
  },
  {
    "orderid": "12696",
    "id": 3929,
    "name": "Close Up",
    "price": 111.15,
    "quantity": 5,
    "order": 1,
    "category": 156
  },
]

const flattened = items.reduce((acc, item) => {
  return [
    ...acc, // previous items
    ...Array.from({ length: item.quantity }, () => ({...item})) // current item repeated 'quantity' times
  ]
}, []);

console.log(flattened);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Array#flatMap and Array.from

```js
const input = [
  {
    "orderid": "12696",
    "id": 5180,
    "name": "Crema Chantilly 250 Ml",
    "price": 377.2,
    "quantity": 1,
    "order": 0,
    "category": 167
  },
  {
    "orderid": "12696",
    "id": 3929,
    "name": "Close Up",
    "price": 111.15,
    "quantity": 2,
    "order": 1,
    "category": 156
  },
  {
    "orderid": "12696",
    "id": 2739,
    "name": "Hellmanns 232 Ml",
    "price": 92.68,
    "quantity": 2,
    "order": 31,
    "category": 131
  }
];
const result = input.flatMap(i=>Array.from({length:i.quantity},()=>({...i})));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Than you so much !! Thats what i needed!

Answer (score 1):

Oh I like ray hatfield's answer.

Mine is the same thing, but more verbose and less elegant!

```
// Prepare somewhere to store the results
const results = [];

// "mini-items" for brevity:
const items = [{id:1, q:1}, {id:2, q:3}, {id:3, q:2}]; 

for (let item of items){
    
    // repeat "quantity" times, and add to results
    for(i=0;i<item.q;i++) {
      // Make a copy of the item
      let copy = { ...item }; 

      // do something with the copy
      copy.someOtherId = Math.random();

      // Set the copy quantity
      copy.q = 1;

      results.push( copy );
    }
}
// all done!
console.log(results);
```

So basically:
Loop through all the items, and once more for quantity in each.
Make a copy and push it to results.

Comment: thats beautiful. Is there a way to, in top of that, give an intern id for the same products?

Comment: I edited and moved the logic into the inner loop so each clone is different